# Rename columns based on certain pattern

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following columns in a dataframe: `Id, category2, Brandyqdy1, Brandyqwdwdy2, Brandyqdw3`

If the column's name starts with `Brand` and ends with `1`, I need it renamed as `Vans`. Similarly, for other Brand columns, use the following:
`rename_brands = {'1': 'Vans', '2': 'Nike', 3:'Adidas'}`

Also, I will be renaming other columns apart from the ones that start with `Brand`, overall:
`rename_columns = {'Id': 'record', 'Category2': 'Sku', '1': 'Vans', '2': 'Nike', 3:'Adidas'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the two `rename` method. For regex rename, you can use `re.sub`

```py
import re


rename_brands = {'1': 'Vans', '2': 'Nike', 3:'Adidas'}
rename_columns = {'Id': 'record', 'Category2': 'Sku', '1': 'Vans', '2': 'Nike', '3':'Adidas'}

out = (df.rename(columns=rename_columns)
       .rename(columns=lambda col: re.sub('^Brand.*(\d)$',
                                          lambda m: rename_brands.get(m.group(1), m.group(0)),
                                          col)))
```

```
$ print(df)

   Id  Category2  Brandyqdy1  Brandyqwdwdy2  Brandyqdw3   1   2
0 NaN        NaN         NaN            NaN         NaN NaN NaN


$ print(out)

   record  Sku  Vans  Nike  Brandyqdw3  Vans  Nike
0     NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN         NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

1. Select the columns that do not contain 'Brand' from the dataframe as `df1`. Instead, include 'Brand' as `df2`.
2. Use a `for` loop to replace the columns ending with numbers in df2 corresponding to the `brands` dictionary.
3. `Join` the `df1` and the `df2` together.

**Sample Code**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id':['001', '002'], 
    'Category':['A', 'S'],
    'Brandtxsu1':[1, 1],
    'Brandxyw2':[2, 2]
})

print(df)

print('------------------------------------')

brands = {'1': 'Vans', '2': 'Nike'}

df1 = df[['Id', 'Category']].rename(columns={'Category': 'Record'})

df2 = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.startswith('Brand')]

for i in range(1,3):
    df2 = df2.rename(columns={df2.loc[:, df2.columns.str.endswith(str(i))].columns.values[0]: brands[str(i)]})

df_output = df1.join(df2)

print(df_output)
```

**Output**

```
    Id Category  Brandtxsu1  Brandxyw2
0  001        A           1          2
1  002        S           1          2
------------------------------------
    Id Record  Vans  Nike
0  001      A     1     2
1  002      S     1     2
```